# Is IIS Http daemon?

Tags: http, iis, daemon

I was reading about http daemon and in order to make sense of it I tried to relate it to something I know and I thought that based on its definition it is very similar to IIS, so can we consider the IIS an HTTP daemon or does the IIS include it? I would appreciate it if anyone can clarify the relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a service called the HTTP Stack (http.sys) which is responsible for routing HTTP requests to the proper process, such as IIS.

When the IIS service runs, it registers any URLs that it wants to handle with http.sys. This makes it possible to have multiple processes share port 80 as long as they request different URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there's basically no daemon on Windows, but the collaboration between http.sys and IIS works on behalf of a daemon?

Comment: Both http.sys and IIS are arguably daemons. It might be helpful to explain what distinction you're trying to draw.

Comment: Services in Windows are similar to daemons on *nix systems.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable answers